# How to display tables below each subplot using axis labels as column headers

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to display a data table under each of two subplots in figure, which I have plotted using pandas' `plot` function. I have got the plots to look as I want, and can get one of the two tables to show up under one of the two subplots, but it is unreadable (and only one of the two I want to display).

My goal is to have each plot and table look something like this: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/table_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-misc-table-demo-py where the axes act as column headers and the data is directly beneath each plot. Unfortunately, my figure is not coming out like that. Below is my code, which if run should produce exactly what I'm seeing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set up df
rowcol = {'ID':[101,101,101,101], 'Assessment': ['Read-Write-1','Math-1', 'Read-Write-Math-3', 'Read-Write-Math-4'],
          'Math': [np.nan,4,3,3], 'MScore': [np.nan, 636.5, 577.2, 545.4],
          'RW': [3, np.nan, 3, 3], 'RWScore': [559.7, np.nan, 621.6, 563.7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = rowcol)
df = df.interpolate()

# Set up subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharex=True)
df.plot(x='Assessment', y=['MScore', 'RWScore'], use_index = True, 
        grid = True, style=['+r-.', 'xb--'], legend=['MScore','RWScore'], 
        ax=axes[0], xticks=[0,1,2,3])
df.plot(x='Assessment', y=['Math', 'RW'], use_index = True, 
        grid = True, style=['+g-.', 'xc--'], legend=['M','RW'], 
        xticks=[0,1,2,3], ylim=[0,4], yticks=[1,2,3,4], ax=axes[1])

# Add labels, titles, and legend
axes[0].set_title(df['ID'][0])
axes[1].set_title(df['ID'][0])
plt.xlabel('Assessment')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Score')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Performance Level')
plt.legend(loc='best')

# Add data tables
table1 = plt.table(cellText = [df.MScore, df.RWScore],
                   rowLabels = ['MScore', 'RWScore'],
                   rowColours = ['r','b'], loc='bottom',
                   colLabels = df['Assessment'])
table2 = plt.table(cellText = [df.Math, df.RW],
                   rowLabels = ['Math', 'RW'],
                   rowColours = ['g','c'], loc='bottom',
                   colLabels = df['Assessment'])

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

As you can see, this does not produce anything particularly pretty, or even readable. What needs to be changed in this code to make it work as in the example in the link?

Comment: Currently your xaxis ranges from 0 to 3. But in order for the ticks to be aligned with the table, it should rather range from -0.5 to 3.5, or more generally to `n+0.5` with `n` being the number of unique labels in the x column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What needs to be changed in this code to make it work as in the example in the link?

The dataset in the example is quite different from the one in your question. In addition, there are two subplots and tables involved. For readability sake, you can change the code to increase the figure sizes, make space for the tables, show table below each subplot, hide the xticklabels and the x-axis labels.

```
rowcol = {'ID':[101,101,101,101], 'Assessment': ['Read-Write-1','Math-1', 'Read-Write-Math-3', 'Read-Write-Math-4'],
          'Math': [np.nan,4,3,3], 'MScore': [np.nan, 636.5, 577.2, 545.4],
          'RW': [3, np.nan, 3, 3], 'RWScore': [559.7, np.nan, 621.6, 563.7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = rowcol)
df = df.interpolate()
# print(df)
# Set up subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(30, 10)) #specify size of subplots
df.plot(x='Assessment', y=['MScore', 'RWScore'], use_index = True, 
        grid = True, style=['+r-.', 'xb--'], legend=['MScore','RWScore'], 
        ax=axes[0], xticks=[0,1,2,3])
df.plot(x='Assessment', y=['Math', 'RW'], use_index = True, 
        grid = True, style=['+g-.', 'xc--'], legend=['M','RW'], 
        xticks=[0,1,2,3], ylim=[0,4], yticks=[1,2,3,4], ax=axes[1])


# Add labels, titles, and legend
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3, bottom=0.2, wspace = 0.3)
axes[0].set_title(df['ID'][0])
axes[1].set_title(df['ID'][0])
axes[0].set_ylabel('Score')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Performance Level')
#set visibility of x-axis and y-axis, xticklabels and yticklabels
axes[0].xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
axes[1].xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
axes[0].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axes[1].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.legend(loc='best')


# Add data tables for each subplot
table1 = axes[0].table(cellText = [df.MScore, df.RWScore],
                   rowLabels = ['MScore', 'RWScore'],
                   rowColours = ['r','b'], loc='bottom',
                   colLabels = df['Assessment'])
table2 = axes[1].table(cellText = [df.Math, df.RW],
                   rowLabels = ['Math', 'RW'],
                   rowColours = ['g','c'], loc='bottom',
                   colLabels = df['Assessment'], fontsize=15)

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: So it automatically knows to set the column headers as the axis values? Because it is never specified anywhere.

Comment: The column labels are specified with the following arg: `colLabels = df['Assessment']`